# Unknown provider: ngDialogProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been using ngDialog in my controller called PatientCommonController and it has been working perfectly as intended.
The problem arises when I run 'grunt test' for testing my code.
While searching on stackoverflow for the solution I tried this fix: ["Unknown provider: ngDialogProvider"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576160/unknown-provider-ngdialogprovider)

It didnt work out for me.What am I doing wrong?

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ngDialogProvider <- ngDialog <- PatientCommonController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/unpr?p0=ngDialogProvider%20%3C-%20ngDialog%20%3C-%20PatientCommonController in /home/krishnanspace/Projects_2/bahmni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps/ui/app/components/angular/angular.js (line 68)
minErr/<@/home/krishnanspace/Projects_2/bahmni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps/ui/app/components/angular/angular.js:68:12
createInjector/providerCache.$injector<@/home/krishnanspace/Projects_2/bahmni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps/ui/app/components/angular/angular.js:4346:19
getService@/home/krishnanspace/Projects_2/bahmni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps/ui/app/components/angular/angular.js:4494:39
createInjector/instanceCache.$injector<@/home/krishnanspace/Projects_2/bahmni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps/ui/app/components/angular/angular.js:4351:28
getService@/home/krishnanspace/Projects_2/bahmni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps/ui/app/components/angular/angular.js:4494:39
invoke@/home/krishnanspace/Projects_2/bahmni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps/ui/app/components/angular/angular.js:4526:13
instantiate@/home/krishnanspace/Projects_2/bahmni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps/ui/app/components/angular/angular.js:4543:27
$ControllerProvider/this.$get</<@/home/krishnanspace/Projects_2/bahmni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps/ui/app/components/angular/angular.js:9395:18
angular.mock.$ControllerDecorator</<@/home/krishnanspace/Projects_2/bahmni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps/ui/app/components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1960:12
@/home/krishnanspace/Projects_2/bahmni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps/ui/test/unit/registration/controllers/patientCommonController.spec.js:40:9

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ngDialogProvider <- ngDialog <- PatientCommonController <- PatientCommonController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/unpr?p0=ngDialogProvider%20%3C-%20ngDialog%20%3C-%20PatientCommonController%20%3C-%20PatientCommonController in /home/krishnanspace/Projects_2/bahmni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps/ui/app/components/angular/angular.js (line 68)
minErr/<@/home/krishnanspace/Projects_2/bahmni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps/ui/app/components/angular/angular.js:68:12
createInjector/providerCache.$injector<@/home/krishnanspace/Projects_2/bahmni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps/ui/app/components/angular/angular.js:4346:19
getService@/home/krishnanspace/Projects_2/bahmni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps/ui/app/components/angular/angular.js:4494:39
createInjector/instanceCache.$injector<@/home/krishnanspace/Projects_2/bahmni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps/ui/app/components/angular/angular.js:4351:28
getService@/home/krishnanspace/Projects_2/bahmni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps/ui/app/components/angular/angular.js:4494:39
invoke@/home/krishnanspace/Projects_2/bahmni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps/ui/app/components/angular/angular.js:4526:13
instantiate@/home/krishnanspace/Projects_2/bahmni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps/ui/app/components/angular/angular.js:4543:27
$ControllerProvider/this.$get</<@/home/krishnanspace/Projects_2/bahmni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps/ui/app/components/angular/angular.js:9395:18
angular.mock.$ControllerDecorator</<@/home/krishnanspace/Projects_2/bahmni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps/ui/app/components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1960:12
createController@/home/krishnanspace/Projects_2/bahmni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps/ui/test/unit/registration/controllers/patientCommonController.spec.js:182:13
@/home/krishnanspace/Projects_2/bahmni/openmrs-module-bahmniapps/ui/test/unit/registration/controllers/patientCommonController.spec.js:289:13
```

EDIT 1:My Test File

```
'use strict';
```

describe('PatientCommonController', function () {

```
var $aController, $httpBackend, scope, appService, rootScope,  patientAttributeService;
var spinner = jasmine.createSpyObj('spinner', ['forPromise']);

beforeEach(module('bahmni.registration'));

beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('patientAttributeService', {});
}));

beforeEach(
    inject(function ($controller, _$httpBackend_, $rootScope) {
        $aController = $controller;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        rootScope = $rootScope;
    })
);


beforeEach(function () {
    appService = jasmine.createSpyObj('appService', ['getAppDescriptor']);

    rootScope.genderMap = {};

    scope.patient = {};

    appService.getAppDescriptor = function () {
        return {
            getConfigValue: function (config) {
                return true;
            }

        };
    };

    $aController('PatientCommonController', {
        $scope: scope,
        $rootScope: rootScope,
        appService: appService
    });

    $httpBackend.whenGET(Bahmni.Common.Constants.globalPropertyUrl + '?property=concept.reasonForDeath').respond({});
    $httpBackend.when('GET', Bahmni.Common.Constants.conceptUrl).respond({});
    $httpBackend.flush();

});


it("should make calls for reason for death global property and concept sets", function () {
    $httpBackend.expectGET(Bahmni.Common.Constants.globalPropertyUrl);
    $httpBackend.expectGET(Bahmni.Common.Constants.conceptUrl);
});

it("should show caste same as last name if the configuration is set to true", function () {

    rootScope.patientConfiguration = {attributeTypes: [{name: 'Caste'}, {name: 'Class'}]};

    expect(scope.showCasteSameAsLastName()).toBeTruthy();
});

it("should show caste same as last name if the configuration is set to true irrespective of patient attribute case sensitivity", function () {
    rootScope.patientConfiguration = {attributeTypes: [{name: 'caSTe'}, {name: 'Class'}]};

    expect(scope.showCasteSameAsLastName()).toBeTruthy();
});

it("should not show caste same as last name if the configuration is set to true, but person attribute caste is not there", function () {
    rootScope.patientConfiguration = {attributeTypes: [{name: 'Class'}]};

    expect(scope.showCasteSameAsLastName()).toBeFalsy();
});

it("showBirthTime should be true by default", function () {
    expect(scope.showBirthTime).toBe(true);
});

it("showBirthTime should be false if set false", function () {

    appService.getAppDescriptor = function () {
        return {
            getConfigValue: function (config) {
                if (config == "showBirthTime") {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };
    };

    $aController('PatientCommonController', {
        $scope: scope,
        $rootScope: rootScope,
        http: $httpBackend,
        patientAttributeService: patientAttributeService,
        spinner: spinner,
        appService: appService
    });
    expect(scope.showBirthTime).toBe(false);
});

describe("show or hide sections", function () {
    var sections;
    var createController = function () {
        appService = jasmine.createSpyObj('appService', ['getAppDescriptor']);

        rootScope.genderMap = {};

        scope.patientLoaded = true;
        var showOrHideSection = function (patient) {
            var returnValues = {
                show: [],
                hide: []
            };
            if (patient["age"].years < 18) {
                returnValues.show.push("additionalPatientInformation")
            } else {
                returnValues.hide.push("additionalPatientInformation")
            }
            return returnValues
        };

        var showOrHideSectionOfCareTaker = function (patient) {
            var returnValues = {
                show: [],
                hide: []
            };
            if (patient["legalRepAlsoCaretaker"] && patient["legalRepAlsoCaretaker"].value.fullySpecifiedName === "Yes") {
                returnValues.show.push("caretaker");
            } else {
                returnValues.hide.push("caretaker");
            }
            return returnValues
        }
        Bahmni.Registration.AttributesConditions.rules = {
            'age': function (patient) {
                return showOrHideSection(patient);
            },

            'birthdate': function (patient) {
                return showOrHideSection(patient);
            },
            'legalRepAlsoCaretaker': function (patient) {
                return showOrHideSectionOfCareTaker(patient);
            }
        };

        sections = {
            "additionalPatientInformation": {
                attributes: [{
                    name: "education"
                }, {
                    foo: "bar"
                }]
            },
            "caretaker": {
                attributes: [{
                    name: "something"
                }, {
                    foo: "bar"
                }]
            }
        };

        rootScope.patientConfiguration = {
            getPatientAttributesSections: function () {
                return sections;
            }
        };

        appService.getAppDescriptor = function () {
            return {
                getConfigValue: function (config) {
                    return true;
                }

            };
        };

        $aController('PatientCommonController', {
            $scope: scope,
            $rootScope: rootScope,
            appService: appService
        });

        $httpBackend.whenGET(Bahmni.Common.Constants.globalPropertyUrl + '?property=concept.reasonForDeath').respond({});
        $httpBackend.when('GET', Bahmni.Common.Constants.conceptUrl).respond({});
        $httpBackend.flush();

    };
    it("should show additional attributes section if age is less than 18 on page load", function () {
        scope.patient = {
            'age': {
                years: 10
            }
        };

        createController();
        expect(sections.additionalPatientInformation.canShow).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it("should hide additional attributes section if age is greater than 18 on page load", function () {

        scope.patient = {
            'age': {
                years: 20
            }
        };

        createController();
        expect(sections.additionalPatientInformation.canShow).toBeFalsy();
    });

    it("should hide caretaker attributes section if legalRepAlsoCaretaker is selected as 'No'", function () {
        scope.patient = {
            'age': {
                years: 20
            },
            'legalRepAlsoCaretaker': {
                'value': {
                    fullySpecifiedName: "No"
                }
            }
        };

        createController();
        expect(sections.caretaker.canShow).toBeFalsy();
    });

    it("should hide caretaker attributes section on page load", function () {
        scope.patient = {
            'age': {
                years: 20
            }
        }

        createController();
        expect(sections.caretaker.canShow).toBeFalsy();
    });

    it("should show or hide caretaker attributes section if legalRepAlsoCaretaker value changes ", function () {

        scope.patient = {
            'age': {
                years: 20
            }
        };

        createController();
        expect(sections.caretaker.canShow).toBeFalsy();

        scope.patient = {
            'age': {
                years: 20
            },
            'legalRepAlsoCaretaker': {
                'value': {
                    fullySpecifiedName: "Yes"
                }
            }
        };
        scope.handleUpdate('legalRepAlsoCaretaker');
        expect(sections.caretaker.canShow).toBeTruthy();

        scope.patient = {
            'age': {
                years: 20
            },
            'legalRepAlsoCaretaker': {
                'value': {
                    fullySpecifiedName: "No"
                }
            }
        };
        scope.handleUpdate('legalRepAlsoCaretaker');
        expect(sections.caretaker.canShow).toBeFalsy();

    });
    it("should hide additional attributes section if age is greater than 18 on value change", function () {

        scope.patient = {
            'age': {
                years: 10
            }
        };

        createController();
        expect(sections.additionalPatientInformation.canShow).toBeTruthy();

        scope.patient = {
            'age': {
                years: 20
            }
        };
        scope.handleUpdate('age');
        expect(sections.additionalPatientInformation.canShow).toBeFalsy();

        scope.patient = {
            'age': {
                years: 8
            }
        };
        scope.handleUpdate('age');
        expect(sections.additionalPatientInformation.canShow).toBeTruthy();
    })
})})
```

Comment: make sure you've used `ngDialog` in your module dependency like : `app.module('app', [..., 'ngDialog'])`

Comment: Can you post your testing.js file ?

Comment: @PrashantGhimire It is injected in my module as you have mentioned above

Comment: @RameshRajendran Added the test File

Comment: Yeah! You didn't inject your `ngDialogProvider
` model in test. if you add this then the error will gone. see my below answer and the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most of the time people get this error because they didn't include the modules:

```
beforeEach(module('ngDialogProvider'));
```

Please check it out : [Getting Unknown Provider error when injecting a Service into an Angular unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807026/getting-unknown-provider-error-when-injecting-a-service-into-an-angular-unit-tes)

Comment: Thanks man!!!It didn't work when I injected "ngDialogProvider" but when I injected "ngDialog" in your above statement!.